# Accessing cells of a matrix to use in a for loop (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, matrix, element

I seem to have a problem in regards to assigning a value from a matrix I created to a certain variable using a for loop. I am using different pairs of angles to create a plot and I want to access those elements in the for loop to generate values for Q1 and Q2.

Code:

```
L1=input('Enter the length of Link 1:' );
L2=input('Enter the length of Link 2:' );
i=0:5:180;
j=0:5:180;
[p,q] = meshgrid(i, j);
pairs = [p(:) q(:)];
for k = 1 : size(pairs)
Q1(k)=pairs(k,1);
Q2(k)=pairs(k,2);
PEx(k)=(L1.*cosd(Q1))+(cosd(Q1).*cosd(Q2).*L2);
PEy(k)=(L1.*sind(Q1))+(sind(Q1).*cosd(Q2).*L2);
PEz(k)=(-L2.*sind(Q2));
end
```

The error:
    "In an assignment A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same."

Thank you

Comment: Which line does the error refer to?

Comment: Try to use the matlab debugger to understand the problem better. I think the error message is rather clear. Secondly, if you create a [mcve], please avoid asking for user input, just use some sample values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `for k = 1:size(pairs,2)` to get the number of *rows* in `pairs`, otherwise `size` will return `[nrows ncols]`.

Then when you're assigning to `PEx` etc, you're using the entire `Q1` and `Q2` vectors, instead of the most recent element. Instead use (for example)

```
PEz(k)=(-L2.*sind(Q2(k)));
```

Then your code becomes:

```
L1=input('Enter the length of Link 1:' );
L2=input('Enter the length of Link 2:' );
i=0:5:180;
j=0:5:180;
[p,q] = meshgrid(i, j);
pairs = [p(:) q(:)];
for k = 1:size(pairs,2)
    Q1(k)=pairs(k,1);
    Q2(k)=pairs(k,2);
    PEx(k)=(L1.*cosd(Q1(k)))+(cosd(Q1(k)).*cosd(Q2(k)).*L2);
    PEy(k)=(L1.*sind(Q1(k)))+(sind(Q1(k)).*cosd(Q2(k)).*L2);
    PEz(k)=(-L2.*sind(Q2(k)));
end
```

---

However, you can remove the loop by vectorizing your code:

```
% Get inputs (you should probs have more validation checks here, maybe use 's' flag)
L1 = input('L1: '); L2 = input('L2: ');
% Set up pairs, avoid i and j as variable names, equal sqrt(-1) by default in MATLAB
ii = 0:5:180;
[p, q] = meshgrid(ii,ii);
% Skip assigning pairs, as it's just used as separate p and q anyway
Q1 = p(:); Q2 = q(:);
% Instead of looping just assign directly. You've already (correctly) used element-wise .*
PEx =(L1.*cosd(Q1))+(cosd(Q1).*cosd(Q2).*L2);
PEy = (L1.*sind(Q1))+(sind(Q1).*cosd(Q2).*L2);
PEz = (-L2.*sind(Q2));
```

Comment: I've been writing my answer and saw your answer. You are too fast! :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the assignment of:

```
PEx(k)=(L1.*cosd(Q1))+(cosd(Q1).*cosd(Q2).*L2);
```

You are assigning a 1x2 to a 1x1 variable. It's also gonna happen with the following `PEy` and `PEz` since you are doing `cosd` and `sind` with a pair and the output already is a 1x2.

Maybe you have to reconsider how you are storing the results of the link calculation, but the error is there.

Comment: chill buddy, when I uploaded it I didn't saw your "more thorough answer"

Comment: So should I delete this? I always see post where people outcome with answers in different level of specification. I mean, I just notice why his code was failing, and gave him what I think is an advice. You instead gave him a solution telling him to vectorize his code, wich is totally perfect, more efficient, but don't give any room for him to learn trough his own code.

Comment: Nice, it's good to have another user input on this, I'll change the way I answer questions and I'll try to approach the model you use, it makes sense. Sorry if I got defensive on your first comment, it sounds a little rude to me considering last experiences I had with other users

Comment: No worries, it's temping to provide answers rather than comments when you're low rep as there's a chance you'll gain upvotes, but it's good to imagine how useful an answer would be to a future site visitor who *isn't* the OP, then there's motivation to be more solution-oriented. I've cleaned up my comments on this post to keep things on topic.